# Chartist.js, SVG circle element is not showing up in the container

Tags: svg, chartist.js

I'm using Chartist.js to work on a pie chart.
I am trying to add a simple circle in the background, but for some reason the circle element just ends up in the top left corner with 0x0 dimensions.

Here is the SVG:

```
<div class="contents" id="chart-container">
    <svg xmlns:ct="http://gionkunz.github.com/chartist-js/ct" width="100%" height="100%" class="ct-chart-pie" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" viewBox="0 0 359 219">
        <g class="basecircle">
            <cirlce class="basecircleelement" cx="10" cy="10" fill="black" cr="181.76999999999998">
            </cirlce>
        </g>
        <g ct:series-name="value" class="ct-series ct-series-a">
            <path d="M147.071,10.108A104.375,104.375,0,1,0,179.325,5L179.325,109.375Z" class="ct-slice-pie" ct:value="95" style="fill: gray; stroke: white; stroke-width: #fff;"></path>
        </g>
        <g ct:series-name="rest" class="ct-series ct-series-b">
            <path d="M179.325,5A104.375,104.375,0,0,0,146.725,10.222L179.325,109.375Z" class="ct-slice-pie" ct:value="5" style="fill: transparent;"></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

I expected the "g.basecircle" and "circle.basecircleelement" should be showing up(It's supposed to be in the center of the container but I didn't calculate the cx and cy yet) with radius of 181.76999999999998 -this value is calculated to be half of the clientWidth-, but it ends up in the upper left corner of the SVG element with dimension of 0 x 0

Is there anything I am missing?

[image]

Comment: cirlce is not the correct spelling of circle

Comment: @Robert Longson OMG that's embarrassing. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this value is calculated to be half of the clientWidth-, but it ends
>   up in the upper left corner of the SVG element with dimension of 0 x 0

Typos must be fixed:
`circle` instead of`cirlce`

Radius designation -`r` instead of`cr`

Svg canvas borders are bounded by a red square `style = "border: 1px solid red;"`

It is very convenient to visually see the borders of SVG. When you finish debugging your application, this line can be removed.

To place the black circle in the center of the svg canvas, you need to set the coordinates `cx =" 359/2 "` `cy =" 219/2 "`

```html
<div class="contents" id="chart-container">
    <svg xmlns:ct="http://gionkunz.github.com/chartist-js/ct" width="100%" height="100%" class="ct-chart-pie"  viewBox="0 0 359 219" style="border:1px solid red;">
        <g class="basecircle">
            <circle class="basecircleelement" cx="179.5" cy="109.5" fill="black" r="179.5">
            </circle>
        </g>
        <g ct:series-name="value" class="ct-series ct-series-a">
            <path d="M147.071,10.108A104.375,104.375,0,1,0,179.325,5L179.325,109.375Z" class="ct-slice-pie" ct:value="95" style="fill: gray; stroke: white; stroke-width: #fff;"></path>
        </g>
        <g ct:series-name="rest" class="ct-series ct-series-b">
            <path d="M179.325,5A104.375,104.375,0,0,0,146.725,10.222L179.325,109.375Z" class="ct-slice-pie" ct:value="5" style="fill: transparent;"></path>
        </g>
  
    </svg>
</div>
```

**Update**

If you want the black circle to not form and completely fit on the canvas `svg` you need to set its radius equal to half the height of the canvas `r= 219 / 2 = 109.5`

```html
<div class="contents" id="chart-container">
    <svg xmlns:ct="http://gionkunz.github.com/chartist-js/ct" width="100%" height="100%" class="ct-chart-pie"  viewBox="0 0 359 219" style="border:1px solid red;">
        <g class="basecircle">
            <circle class="basecircleelement" cx="179.5" cy="109.5" fill="black" r="109.5">
            </circle>
        </g>
        <g ct:series-name="value" class="ct-series ct-series-a">
            <path d="M147.071,10.108A104.375,104.375,0,1,0,179.325,5L179.325,109.375Z" class="ct-slice-pie" ct:value="95" style="fill: gray; stroke: white; stroke-width: #fff;"></path>
        </g>
        <g ct:series-name="rest" class="ct-series ct-series-b">
            <path d="M179.325,5A104.375,104.375,0,0,0,146.725,10.222L179.325,109.375Z" class="ct-slice-pie" ct:value="5" style="fill: transparent;"></path>
        </g>
  
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: @K.H. Look at the finalized example, please

Comment: It turned out the typo was the cause. Thanks a lot for the example too. I could make some improvements to the final code and the issue is now fixed :)